# Linux DNS Bind Domain Subdomain Configuration

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

I have a question about configuration of bind for domain and subdomain.

For example, I have the main domain of "example.lcl", and under that I have the subdomain of "alpha.example.lcl" at site A and "beta.example.lcl" at site B.

The Linux DNS server at site A is authoritative for "example.lcl" and "alpha.example.lcl".

I was wondering how the zone should be configured and how the forward and reverse lookup zone files should be configured.

Comment: Can you clarify what aspects you're unclear on - the ideal delegation or master/slave structure, or actually configuring the zones and zone files on each server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to delegate beta.example.lcl to different DNS servers, use NS records in the example.lcl zone like so:

```
@  IN A 10.0.0.1
alpha IN A 10.0.0.1

beta IN NS some.other.dns.server.example.net.
beta IN NS another.other.dns.server.example.net.
```

on the other hand, if you want to keep everything on your existing DNS servers, and you can make alpha and beta hostnames under one zone:

```
@ IN A 10.0.0.1
alpha IN A 10.0.0.1

beta IN A 10.9.2.5
```

and so on...